# Turn advertisements off or on for members on Wordpress website?

Tags: wordpress, ads

Does anyone know how I could enable members who created an account on my WordPress website (http://developergenius.com) to be able to disable disable advertisements in the My Account (http://developergenius.com/my-account) page on my website? I want it where they could just hit a check box and then hit save and advertisements would disappear, then they could always turn them on again.
Please note that I am kind of a beginner, sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

The thing you are looking for is:

[is user logged in](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/is_user_logged_in)

this is a built in wordpress function you can use.

for example:

```
<?php
if ( is_user_logged_in() ) {
    echo 'Welcome, registered user!';
} else {
    echo 'Welcome, visitor!';
}
?>
```

you can play with it and add functions to the control panel, to the actual site and more.

if you want more options you should also see:

[Roles and Capabilities](http://codex.wordpress.org/Roles_and_Capabilities)

This feature gives you the power to what kind of user is logged. (admin, user, subscriber and so)